# Strange behavior of Property.valueChangeListener of Select UI / Vaadin 6.7.3

Tags: selection, vaadin

I tried to catch when the selection list is changed, but the following code is fired when
I open up selection list, not when a new list item become selected.

```
this.select.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {

public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) 
    {           
     System.out.println(event.getProperty());
    }
});
```

Why did I wrong, how can I catch every new selected value in time ?

Here comes what happens (youtube video - temporary) http://goo.gl/m7dNi

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Cs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set your select into immediate mode:

```
select.setImmediate(true);
```

Comment: I know about `setImmediate()` method. But actually , most of times I forgot to set it ( *eg: when adding addValueChangeListener to a component*) :-) . Thanks.

Comment: @Cataclysm In fact, Vaadin 7.2 makes a component implicitly immediate when you add a ValueChangeListener on it.